# MSBuild remoting to server throws COMException error

Tags: msbuild, comexception

Ive got an MSBUILD script where ive set the Username and Password properties as below

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7AppPool TaskAction="CheckExists" Name="@(WebSite -> '%(Name)')" MachineName="@(WebSite -> '%(MachineName)')" Username="username" UserPassword="password">
```

This throws the following error :

COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine MYSERVER01 failed due to the following error: 800706ba MYSERVER01

Ports 135,445 are open.... 
Eventlog showing up "DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer using any of the configured protocols"

Firewalls are all currently disabled.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: Telneting to the ports fails....Ports havent been opened yet it seems in our DMZ...which is most likely the cause of this

Comment: Ports have been opened and this has resolved this error.